# Как создать подготовленный запрос с IN()?

Tags: php, pdo

Метод `getPromosUser()` принимает массив `$id_promos_user`. Далее элементы массива складываются в строку: `$id_promos_user = join(',', $id_promos_user)`.

Если в массиве несколько значений, то в подготовленый запрос попадает только первое значение до запятой. Например, `$id_promos_user = "30003113,30004075"`, то в запрос попадает только `WHERE id_remote IN (30003113)`.

Как сделать так, чтобы через подготовленый запрос в селект попала вся строка `WHERE id_remote IN (30003113,30004075)`?

```
public function getPromosUser($id_promos_user)
{
    $db = DataBase::getConnection();

    $id_promos_user = join(',', $id_promos_user);
    $sql = "SELECT  id,
                    id_remote,
                    bonus,
                    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(start)) AS start,
                    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(end))   AS end
                FROM promos
                WHERE id_remote IN (:id_promos_user)
                ORDER BY end";

    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':id_promos_user', $id_promos_user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    print_r($result);
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($row);

    return array('body' => $row);
}
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#in

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать в запросе столько плейсхолдеров, сколько у вас id в массиве. Именованный плейсхолдер в этом случае использовать не получится (вернее, получится, но незачем и усложнит код):

```
$placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($id_promos_user) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM promos WHERE id_remote IN ($placeholders)");
$sth->execute($id_promos_user);
```