# PDO подготовленный запрос с IN()

Tags: php, sql, pdo

При переходе на PDO, уперся в очередную "засаду".

Есть запрос (упрощен до нельзя для простоты понимания)

```
SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE num IN(:num)

$itog->bindValue(':num', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,);

$itog->execute();
```

Пробовал и массив передавать в bindValue и циклом его выводить и еще разные варианты, но итог один... Выводится ТОЛЬКО ПЕРВАЯ ЦИФРА из всего ряда.

Тоесть как не крути, а запрос получается только

```
SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE num IN(1 или 2 или 3 или 4 или т.д),
```

но никак не

```
SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE num IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Подскажите плз умным словом (хоть намек куда думать).

Видел тут идентичную тему

[Как создать подготовленный запрос с IN()?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549883/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-in)

и там только один ответ и он удручает. Неужели всесильный PDO действительно без костыля не может "переварить" такую задачу.

Comment: А что эти цифры означают? Номера товаров?

Comment: нет. Цифры это определенные параметры, которые могут быть одинаковыми у разных товаров и надо выборку делать всех товаров с такими параметрами (как пример, размеры одежды.)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то делайте через форму. Типа input type="text" или type="radio" (как вам удобнее) и полученные данные($_POST['num']) записываете в bindValue.

Comment: Как происходит выборка? Пользователь сам выбирает эти параметры?

Comment: Если да, то делаешь так: в бд создаешь еще пару полей(длина, ширина, материал и т.д.) соответственно несколько bindValue будет. Затем делаешь выборку и пришедшие данные сверяешь с данными из бд и выводишь, т.е. 'SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE size=:size AND weight=:weight' и т.д.

Comment: Евгений. Боюсь, что Вы не правильно поняли мой вопрос. Речь идет именно о IN(). Это метод, который фильтрует данные исходя из совпадения внутри IN. тоесть не просто size=:size AND weight=:weight,а   size=:size AND weight=:weight WHERE num IN(implode(','$num)) и так далее

Comment: *Неужели всесильный PDO действительно без костыля не может "переварить" такую задачу.* Так ведь задача-то сама по себе - костыль. Нереляционная она... и неча на PDO кивать, что он не может сделать из дерьма конфетку.

Comment: Akina, возможно мой метод построения запроса и говнокод, учусь только, но тогда подскажите плз, чем заменить ln() в запросе, когда связаны две таблицы и надо вывести товары по id одной таблицы исходя из совпадений в другой по параметрам, часто повторяющимися у продукта в первой таблице? И количество параметров может быть от 1 до 50

Comment: Вопрос не в говнокоде. WHERE .. IN сама по себе хреновая конструкция, попытка "упростить" цепочку OR-ов. *связаны две таблицы и надо вывести товары по id одной таблицы исходя из совпадений в другой по параметрам, часто повторяющимися у продукта в первой таблице? И количество параметров может быть от 1 до 50* Ну с двумя таблицами понятно - JOIN он и в Африке JOIN. А чтобы всё получилось гладко - нужна третья таблица (скажем, Filters), куда кладём эти наборы критериев и всё тем же JOIN с группировкой и подсчётом количества совпадений получаем требуемое.

Comment: "нужна третья таблица (скажем, Filters), куда кладём эти наборы критериев и всё тем же JOIN с группировкой и подсчётом количества совпадений получаем требуемое" как вариант. Попробую разнести и поменять запрос. Но если все таки вернуться к моему вопросу. Может ли PDO в подготовленном запросе разобрать IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, и тд.) ?? Не с позиции как "надо было и не надо было", а просто ДА НЕТ. Если да то как.

Comment: Akina, признаться не понимаю, какую роль будет играть третья таблица? Сейчас у меня есть таблица  tovat в которой основные данные о товаре и вторая таблица parameter в которой сохраняются параметры для конкретного id соответствующего id в таблице tovar. Что должна в себе содержать третья таблица, которую Вы советуете сделать? Ведь в IN() передаются выбранные пользователем чекбоксы и их может быть от 1 до 50. Как кроме IN()можно проверить соответствие параметрам выбранных чекбоксов?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно решение нашел такое.

`$param = str_repeat('?,', count($_GET['param']) - 1) . '?';` получаем ?,?,?,?,? в том количестве, сколько выбрано чек боксов.

```
db->prepare(SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE num IN($param));

db->execute($_GET['param']);
```

Запрос работает как надо, а вот как сделать его безопасным от SQL инъекций кто может подсказать? Не могу никак сообразить...

Comment: Запрос уже безопасный